# I used selenium to scrape a scrolling website and conducted the code below and i have this error selenium python send_key error:

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I used selenium to **scrape** a scrolling website and conducted the code below and I have this error selenium python send_key error:

```
list object has no attribute
```

```
from selenium import webdriver



path_to_chrome_driver=r"/var/www/html/env/projet/chromedriver"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(path_to_chrome_driver)


url = 'https://drive.intermarche.com/Home?p=671'

browse = driver.get(url)

div1 =browse.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/section[1]/div/ul/li[1]/div[1]/div[1]')
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: the problem's Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "teste2.py", line 14, in <module>
    div1 =browse.find_elements_by_xpath('//.*[@id="content"]/div/section[1]/div/ul/li[1]/div[1]/div[1]')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_xpath'

Comment: I remember i solve that problem with this code: driver.set_window_size(4096, 3112) #This set bigger "resolution" to load all elements, Test it and answer me please

Comment: Thank you, in fact the error is when I execute the code I see this error on the console "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "teste2.py", line 15, in <module>
    Div1 = browse.find_elements_by_xpath ('// * [div] / div / section [1] / div [1] / div [1] / div [
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_xpath' "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this answer since when you do

```
browse = driver.get(url)
```

`browse` is set to `None` because `driver.get(url)` returns nothing. Replace the above line by these two:

```
driver.get(url)
div1 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/section[1]/div/ul/li[1]/div[1]/div[1]')
```

Actually, just keep working with `driver` object without renaming it.

Comment: Thank you, Mr. And it is the best solution.